# What is the effect of adding variables to an analysis on type 1 and type 2 error?

Tags: experiment-design, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am planning a study where we have a low number of observations. We know we need to control for at least two variables, but other variables also exist that we can control for.

It seems to me that adding variables to an analysis is always best. By controlling for the variables that have the largest effect, we can reduce the probability of a type 1 error. However, will adding more variables always increase the probability of a type 2 error (given the same number of observations)? How can this be shown mathematically?

Comment: Much has been written about this here on CV. Consider searching for answers related to *overfitting* in problems involving variable selection, regression, and modeling.  Another useful search looks for "omitted variable bias."

Comment: A quick search over those terms has been very elucidating. Should I close the question?

Comment: It's up to you.  You might have a more refined version of your question now; if so, you might just as well edit this post rather than starting a new thread.